# Notify value of variable that holds a nested fact - Puppet4

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent, facter

I am trying to understand what the difference is between the following:

```
$major_release = $::facts['os']['release']['major']
$selinux_is_enabled = $::facts['os']['selinux']['enabled']
```

If I put in my manifest:

```
notify { "major release is: ${major_release}": }
```

And then run this on my client side, it returns a value as expected.
If I do the same for the selinux_is_enabled variable, it does not return a value, even though a

```
facter os.selinux.enabled
```

on the client side returns a "false".

Can anyone explain why the notify does not return an expected value for selinux enabled but it does for os release major?

Comment: What do you mean "does not return a value"? You got message: "major release is:" ? Try using this function https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-extlib/blob/master/lib/puppet/parser/functions/echo.rb to get the exect data type and value of $selinux_is_enabled. It could be :undef. Look for echo in the master log.

Comment: @dilyin - I mean it does not return a "true" or "false" even though the output of running a "facter os.selinux.enabled" shows that it should in fact return a "false".